# Change href based on text in a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have a bunch of `<a>` tags with different strings in them. I want to be able to set the url of those tags based on the text inside each individual tag.

For example, I have

```
<a class="list-group-item">example</a>
<a class="list-group-item">example2</a>
<a class="list-group-item">example3</a>
```

and I want to be able to make the url of the first one equal to `/example/`, the second to `/example2/` and the third to `/example3/`.

This jQuery function makes all of the `href="/example/"`

```
$(function(){
    customURL = $( ".list-group-item" ).html();
    $("a").attr("href", customURL)
});
```

Comment: Use a loop to iterate over the elements and take the time to read a couple beginner jQuery tutorials.

Comment: Why can't you generate your `a` tags directly with `href` attribute correctly set ? If you really can't, maybe knowing that [`.attr` can accept a function as second parameter](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) may help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('a.list-group-item').attr('href', function(){
    return '/' + $(this).text() + '/';
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Wap3q/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Use this jQuery:

```
$('.list-group-item').each(function(){
   var $this=$(this);
   var customURL=$this.html();
   $this.attr('href',customURL);
});
```

Comment: Just adding link to docs http://api.jquery.com/html/ which say the .html() function returns the content of the first element in the set of matched elements.  So since there's 3 matched elements, the .html() only returns the contents of the first one, ie: "example".